# Couldn't find all Advertisements with 'id': (all, {:conditions=>["title LIKE ?", "%#{SOMETHING}%"]}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am  trying to make a search advertisements by title.
My `advertisements.rb` model looks like:

```
class Advertisement < ApplicationRecord
  has_many   :advertisement_tags, dependent: :destroy
  has_many   :comments
  has_many   :tags, through: :advertisement_tags
  belongs_to :user

  validates :title,
            :description,
            presence: true

  def self.find_by_tags(tags)
    Advertisement.joins(:tags).where('tags.tag_name IN (?)', 
    tags.split(/[\s,']/))
  end

  def self.find_by_titles(title)
    if title
      title_length = title.split.length
      find(:all, conditions: [(['title LIKE ?'] * title_length).join(' AND ')] + title.split.map { |t| "%#{t}%" })
    else
      find(:all)
    end
  end
end
```

`search_queries_controller.rb`:

```
class SearchQueriesController < ApplicationController
  def search_by_tag
    @advertisements = Advertisement.find_by_tags(tags_params)

    render 'advertisements/index'
  end

  def search_by_title
    @advertisements = Advertisement.find_by_titles(title_params)

    render 'advertisements/index'
  end

  private

  def tags_params
    params.fetch(:tags, '')
  end

  def title_params
    params.fetch(:title, '')
  end
end
```

`_search_title_form.html.slim`

```
=form_tag search_by_title_path, method: :get do
  =label_tag 'Type Title to Search:'
  =text_field_tag :title
  =submit_tag 'Search'
```

And `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index'

  resources :advertisements do
    resources :comments, only: %i[new create delete]
  end

  resource :profile, only: %i[show edit update] do
    get :your_advertisemnts, controller: :profiles, action: :index
  end

  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    registrations: 'users/registrations'
  }

  get :search_by_tag, controller: :search_queries, action: :search_by_tag
  get :search_by_title, controller: :search_queries, action: :search_by_title
end
```

And i get these error `Couldn't find all Advertisements with 'id': (all, {:conditions=>["title LIKE ?", "%#{SOMETHING}%"]}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)`
Searching by tags works fine, but it is more simple, here i want to make the advertisement to be found by any words in its title. For example, title 'Good job for everyone' may be found by queries 'job', 'good job', 'everyone', job for 'everyone' etc.

Comment: `find(:all, ...` is a very old syntax to run queries in Rails that doesn't work anymore in newer versions. But your other code doesn't look like it was implemented against an old Rails version. What version of Rails to you use?

Comment: @spickermann i'm using `rails 5.1.2`

Comment: @spickermann, think i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you use (`find(:all, ...`) is very old (was used in Rails 2) and is not supported by current versions of Rails anymore. Use `where` instead:

```
def self.find_by_titles(title)
  if title.present?
    words = title.split(' ')
    Advertisement.where(
      Array.new(words.length, 'title LIKE ?').join(' AND '),
      *words.map { |word| "%#{word}%" }
    )
  else
    Advertisement.all
  end
end
```